# How to find count of empty array field

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I was searching for one aggregation query which can provide output as per below condition.

```
db.Collection.aggregate(
[{$match: {$and : [
  {"_createdAt": { $gte : new ISODate('2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z')}},{"_createdAt": { $lt : new ISODate('2022-02-02T00:00:00.000Z')}},
  {"ApiRequestType" : "InstrumentDetails"},{"RequesterSystem" : "Generic_Reporting"}]}},
{$group:
  {_id:{day: { $dayOfMonth: "$_createdAt" },month: { $month: "$_createdAt" },year: { $year: "$_createdAt" }},count: { $sum:1 },
    date: { $first: "$_createdAt" }}},
{$project:{date:{$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" }},count: 1,_id: 1,
    numberOfRMCount: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$ResponseMessage" }, then: { $size: "$ResponseMessage" }, else: "NA"}}},
    }])
```

But I am not getting count as per daily empty ResponseMessage field. it giving only NA Pls help on this.

I am getting below output,

```
count   date        numberOfRMCount
49      05-05-2021  NA
35      04-05-2021  NA
```

Require output as per below,

```
count   date        numberOfRMCount
49      05-05-2021  number of empty ResponseMessage fields
35      04-05-2021  number of empty ResponseMessage fields
```

What should I change in Query.

Comment: I don't see `ResponseMessage` field return from the `$group` stage.

Comment: can you share the change what should I make

Comment: Can you add an input example?

Answer (score 0):

You need `"ResponseMessage"` in `$group`.  I used `$push` and I'm pretty sure that means `"ResponseMessage"` will always be an array so checking to see if it is would be redundant.

```js
db.Collection.aggregate([
  { $match: {
      $and: [
        { "_createdAt": { $gte: ISODate("2021-05-01T00:00:00.000Z") } },
        { "_createdAt": { $lt: ISODate("2022-02-02T00:00:00.000Z") } },
        { "ApiRequestType": "InstrumentDetails" },
        { "RequesterSystem": "Generic_Reporting" }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $group: {
      _id: {
        day: { $dayOfMonth: "$_createdAt" },
        month: { $month: "$_createdAt" },
        year: { $year: "$_createdAt" }
      },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      date: { $first: "$_createdAt" },
      "ResponseMessage": { "$push": "$ResponseMessage" }
    }
  },
  { $project: {
      date: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: "$date"
        }
      },
      count: 1,
      _id: 1,
      numberOfRMCount: { $size: "$ResponseMessage" }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nSWzvBiv5QO)